# Is there a table for the density, Young's modulus, and other common properties for the most common materials?

Tags: materials, aerospace-engineering

I've tried googling extensively, but I have not found a single table that contains many of the "common" materials and more than one property. Does anyone have a table from an engineering textbook or has compiled one themself in Excel?

I sadly don't have access to any textbooks myself currently..
With most "common" I mean the most common in the aerospace engineering field. So maybe some composites, plastics, steel, aluminum alloys etc.

Comment: “In Excel”? Well, when I needed values of density for air I typed the values in and used a double vlookup() to interpolate linearly between values as the data had 5 degree steps. Sounds like good practice for you…

Answer (score 0):

I still use one of my favourite refences:

Geick Technical formulae

But mine dates from about 1988. Contains all those  abstruse formulae for areas, volumes, reminders and proofs for theory stress, structures, materials, and lots of fluids, pressure etc

AND has many tables of physical information; density, specific volume, viscosity etc etc

See https://www.boffinsbooks.com.au/books/9783446420298/technical-formulae-9a-engl

Comment: ASM Metals hand book, 1948 ed. is pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Most undergraduate mat sci textbooks have tables like that. Try Van Vlack or Shackelford.